# WebServlet cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**I was able to make my app works again, following the advices of user2821894, but after trying to call a servlet tomcat 7 stopped working again!!
If i try to delete the code where i call my servlet my web app doesent' work!!
Once i have a problem with a servlet tomcat stops working.**

I had problem launching my web project on eclipse.  I had problem with Tomcat 7.
So i 'delete' tomcat 7 from eclipse and then i added it again (again tomcat 7).

now i have no problem launching my web project, but i have problem on my servlet.
For example i get error like

```
 WebServlet cannot be resolved to a type
 The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type
```

I added servlet-api 3.0.jar to my project but i still have these problems.

This is the code of my servlet

```
 package Jeans;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

    import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.TMSchema.Part;


    import javax.servlet.http.Part;



    @WebServlet("/FileUploadDBServlet ")

  //// i got an error here//////////////////////////// 
    @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)  

    public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {


        private String dbURL = "db";
        private String dbUser = "dbuser";
        private String dbPass = "dbpassword";
        String messageMio = "da contorllare";  
        GestioneDB gestioneDB;
        boolean connessione;       
        Connection conn;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {




         String giorno= request.getParameter("giorno");
         String mese= request.getParameter("mese");
         String anno= request.getParameter("anno");         
         String dataFormatoItaliano = giorno + "-" + mese + "-" + anno;     

          String titolo = request.getParameter("titolo");
          String titoletto = request.getParameter("titoletto");
          String testoMouse = request.getParameter("testoMouse");
          String link = request.getParameter("link");
          String data = dataFormatoItaliano;
          String testo = request.getParameter("testo");




          //// i got an error here////////////////////////////
          Part filePart = request.getPart("immaginePrincipale");  






 String didascaliaImmaginePrincipale = request.getParameter("didascaliaImmaginePrincipale");       


            InputStream immaginePrincipale = null; 
            if (filePart != null) {             
                // obtains input stream of the upload file
                immaginePrincipale = filePart.getInputStream();
            }





            String message = null;  

            try {

                  gestioneDB = new GestioneDB(); 
                  conn = gestioneDB.cn();  



                  gestioneDB.inserimentoNews(titolo, titoletto, testoMouse, link, testo, data, immaginePrincipale, didascaliaImmaginePrincipale);



                String sql = "INSERT INTO allegati_news (allegato,didascalia,tipo,id_news,immagine) values (?,?,?,?,?)";




                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, "firstName");
                statement.setString(2, "lastName");
                statement.setInt(3, 1);
                statement.setInt(4,1);            
                if (immaginePrincipale != null) {              
                    statement.setBlob(5, immaginePrincipale);             
                }




                int row = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (row > 0) {
                    message = "File salvato nel db";
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {

                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

               request.setAttribute("Message", gestioneDB.getInserimentoNewMessaggio());



               getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Jeans2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>prova</display-name>
    <servlet-name>prova</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Jeans.prova</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>prova</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prova</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>

    <description></description>
    <display-name>FileUploadDBServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Jeans.FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileUploadDBServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>BlobDisplay</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BlobDisplay</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Jeans.BlobDisplay</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BlobDisplay</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BlobDisplay</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: plz post some code , mention the line if you know which is causing error , and also post errors

Comment: I added my servlet code. Anyway,I got those errors after tomcat started giving me problems. I 'deleted' it from eclipse and then i added it again.
Before it, my web application worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding servlet-api.jar instead of servelt-api-3.0 jar.Stop the server. Refresh the project and then start the server and see. I think it should work. Make sure you are adding the servlet-api.jar from tomcat lib folder. Suppose your tomcat is in C:\Tomcat\lib.
In eclipse right click your project-properties-javabuildpath-add external jars and then select the servlet-api.jar from your tomcat folder

Comment: Now it seems to work.

Comment: Putting the servlet-api into the project is a bad idea..... I recommend the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595797/cant-import-javax-servlet-annotation-webservlet

Comment: Thanks your solution  helped

Answer (score 10):

**Right click on project ---> Properties ---> Java Build Path ---> Add
    Library... ---> Server Runtime ---> Apache Tomcat ----> Finish.**

Answer (score 2):

A possible reason for this error is using a wrong version of Servlet API. `@WebServlet` annotation is supported by **Servlet 3.0**. You must change the version from possibly 2.5 to 3.0. To do this in eclipse, right click your project and open *Properties*. Select *Project Facets* from the left menu of the page shown. Then change the version of *Dynamic Web Module* facet to 3.0.

Another possible reason can be related to your Tomcat version. Tomcat is supporting Servlet 3.0 beggining from version 7.0.

Comment: I already have set Dynamic Web Module to 3.0.
I got those errors after tomcat started giving me problems.
Before it, my web application worked perfectly

Comment: It can be related to your tomcat version. Tomcat 7 provides servlet api 3.0, but tomcat 6. Note that I updated my answer.

Comment: I recommend you to create the project from scratch :)