# why webservlet cannot resolve to a type???? even am tried with servlet3.jar & servlet api.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@webServlet(name="myLogin",urlPatterns={"/login.jlc"}) //cannot be resolve
```

Comment: Probably because you misspelled it. Use an IDE; it will help identify these things.

Comment: Check this link, it might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7599336/6039974

Comment: This `@webServlet` should be `@WebServlet`

Comment: its creating  an error msg ---tomcat server 9 has encountered a problem cannot start @ johnII

Comment: thnxxxxxx @ Veera Kannadiga

Comment: it is now running with servlet-api.jar

Comment: Check  your pom.xml and see is there any duplication of dependency definition.